# Nested lambdas syntax

Tags: c#

I was toying around and noticed that the following wouldn't compile:

```
Func<int> a = ((j) => (() => 3 * j))(1);
```

This seems like a valid statement to me, and the following equivalent (?) statement works in python:

```
print (lambda x: lambda: 3 * x)(1)()
```

Is this just a consequence of the way anonymous functions are dealt with in the runtime?

Comment: It would help if you share the compiler error that you get.

Comment: It's just a consequence of nobody implementing support for this kind of thing as it generally makes no sense to simply create a lambda and then invoke it immediately, you can simplify the expression vastly and then get it to compile.

Comment: it's certainly interesting, but on a side note, what practical use would this have?

Comment: You can use it to create something like a closure: http://rextester.com/XYBB28501. Mostly for fun though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *possible* in C# but not *pretty* - it requires an explicit cast and a lot of parentheses:

```
Func<int> a = ((Func<int, Func<int>>)(j => () => 3 * j))(1);
```

or similarly

```
Func<int, Func<int>> x = j => () => 3 * j;
Func<int> a = x(1);
```

I think the issue here is that C# cannot in general infer the type of a lambda - it can only check that a lambda will match the type of a cast, variable, parameter etc. that it is assigned to. In your version, the outer lambda (`x`) doesn't have a type specified.